# Should Spring SseEmitter.complete() trigger an EventSource reconnect - how to close connection server-side

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, eventsource

I'm trying to set up a Spring SseEmitter to send a sequence of updates of the status of a running job. It seems to be working but:

Whenever I call `emitter.complete()` in in my Java server code, the javascript `EventSource` client calls the registered `onerror` function and then calls my Java endpoint again with a new connection. This happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

I can probably send an explicit "end-of-data" message from Java and then detect that and call `eventSource.close()` on the client, but is there a better way?

What is the purpose of `emitter.complete()` in that case?

Also, if I always have to terminate the connection on the client end, then I guess every connection on the server side will be terminated by either a timeout or a write error, in which case I probably want to manually send back a heartbeat of some kind every few seconds?

It feels like I'm missing something if I'm having to do all this.

Comment: Facing the same problem, where a new request to endpoint is made after emitter::complete is called on the server-side. springBootVersion=2.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: I got something working, but I'm doing it by sending my own custom "stop" event and then closing it on the client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added the following to my Spring boot application to trigger the SSE connection `close()`

**Server Side:**

1. Create a simple controller which returns SseEmitter.
2. Wrap the backend logic in a single thread executor service.
3. Send your events to the SseEmitter.
4. On complete send an event of type complete via the SseEmitter.

   ```
   @RestController
   public class SearchController {

   @Autowired
   private SearchDelegate searchDelegate;

   @GetMapping(value = "/{customerId}/search")
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
   @ApiOperation(value = "Search Sources", notes = "Search Sources")
   @ApiResponses(value = {
           @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "OK"),
           @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized")
   })
   @ResponseBody
   public SseEmitter search(@ApiParam(name = "searchCriteria", value = "searchCriteria", required = true) @ModelAttribute @Valid final SearchCriteriaDto searchCriteriaDto) throws Exception {
       return searchDelegate.route(searchCriteriaDto);
     }
   }



   @Service
   public class SearchDelegate {
   public static final String SEARCH_EVENT_NAME = "SEARCH";
   public static final String COMPLETE_EVENT_NAME = "COMPLETE";
   public static final String COMPLETE_EVENT_DATA = "{\"name\": \"COMPLETED_STREAM\"}";

   @Autowired
   private SearchService searchService;

   private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

   public SseEmitter route(SearchCriteriaDto searchCriteriaDto) throws Exception {
       SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
       executor.execute(() -> {
           try {
               if(!searchCriteriaDto.getCustomerSources().isEmpty()) {
                   searchCriteriaDto.getCustomerSources().forEach(customerSource -> {
                       try {
                           SearchResponse searchResponse = searchService.search(searchCriteriaDto);
                           emitter.send(SseEmitter.event()
                                   .id(customerSource.getSourceId())
                                   .name(SEARCH_EVENT_NAME)
                                   .data(searchResponse));
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           log.error("Error while executing query for customer {} with source {}, Caused by {}",
                                   customerId, source.getType(), e.getMessage());
                       }
                   });
               }else {
                   log.debug("No available customerSources for the specified customer");
               }
               emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().
                       id(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                       .name(COMPLETE_EVENT_NAME)
                       .data(COMPLETE_EVENT_DATA));
               emitter.complete();
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               emitter.completeWithError(ex);
           }
       });
       return emitter;
      }
   }
   ```

**Client Side:**

1. Since we specified the `name` of event on our `SseEmitter`, an event will be dispatched on the browser to the listener for the specified event name; the website source code should use `addEventListener()` to listen for named events. (*Notice: The `onmessage` handler is called if no event name is specified for a message*)
2. Call the `EventSource` on the `COMPLETE` event to release the client connection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

```
var sse = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/federation/api/customers/5d96348feb061d13f46aa6ce/search?nativeQuery=true&queryString=*&size=10&customerSources=1,2,3&start=0');

sse.addEventListener("SEARCH", function(evt) {
   var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
   console.log(data);
});

sse.addEventListener("COMPLETE", function(evt) {
   console.log(evt);
   sse.close();
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing.

Comment: I am still not sure about `emitter.complete()` though. I guess it just ends things on the server side? Because I think anything it transmits will encounter a closed sse on the client side.

Comment: I agree! Look at the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyEmitter.html#complete--

Answer (score 3):

According to the [HTML standard for Server-sent events](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#server-sent-events)

> Clients will reconnect if the connection is closed; a client can be told to stop reconnecting using the HTTP 204 No Content response code.

So Spring's SseEmitter behaves as expected and the purpose of `complete()` is to make sure all the events were sent and then to close the connection.

You need to either implement server-side logic that would return 204 http code on subsequent requests (e.g. by checking session id) or to send a special event and close the connection from client side after receiving it as [suggested by Ashraf Sarhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58981130/3169238)

Comment: Oh, ok a 204. That seems more natural to me than closing from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I'll continue [sergei-kozelko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3169238/sergei-kozelko) answer.

You have to return

```
return new ResponseEntity(emitter, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
```

Method signature should be:

```
public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> route(SearchCriteriaDto searchCriteriaDto)
```